# Copy cell value to active cell on double click

Tags: excel, vba

When I double click on a cell, I want the value of the cell 3 columns to the left to appear in the cell that I double clicked on.

Doesn't work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As   Boolean)
Cancel = True
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, your code works perfectly in office 2010, on double click event for copying cell value from 3rd cell to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = True
  With Target
    .Value = .Offset(0, -3).Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Neither of the above work. When I double click, the cell goes into edit mode but no value. Am I missing something?

Comment: **YES**  it means the code is probably in the wrong place.........it must go in the worksheet code area...............see my edit